# Function an Abstract variable?

Tags: programming-languages, theory

Is a function is nothing more than an abstract variable ?

Comment: Please choose between C and C++ -- they are not the same language. Also, there is no such thing as an "abstract variable" -- please elaborate

Comment: I wish I knew what an "abstract variable" is :))) A function is a function. Voting to close as not a real question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I like your question, but can you expand your line of thinking and what is an "abstract variable"? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's more to functions than just getting a value of, say, `int foo`. A function can have *side-effects*, such as allocating memory or opening a file.  Also, functions in C or C++ don't have to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "a variable that doesn't hold a directly usable value", yes you could consider it as a variable holding the address  of the function.

For example, in language where functions are first-class objects, you can pass a function as a parameter to a function.

Also, in C you can pass a function pointer as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

No functions are used to break code into logical sections to allow reuse and improve readability. Variables are used to hold data.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends upon the language and the meaning of "abstract variable".**

In Scala, for instance, an abstract variable can be defined:

```
trait X {
  val y: Int
}
```

and the variable could even "be a function"!

```
trait MyMath[T] {
  // abstract
  val square: (T) => T
}

object IntegerMath extends MyMath[Int] {
  // concrete value (implementation) given to [previously-]abstract variable
  val square = (i: Int) => i * i
}

IntegerMath.square(2) // 4
```

So ... "it depends". However, note that *before* being invoked, however, a *concrete* function had to be supplied. If it's never invoked (e.g. it's just a signature) then it doesn't *necessarily* have to have a *concrete* implementation.

C# supports the notion of [Partial Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) which are *truly abstract* and *don't make it into the resulting build* if not given an implementation. They are not, however, variables.

> > If the implementation is not supplied, then the method and all calls to the method are removed at compile time.

There are many more different kinds of programming languages -- some without side-effects (*gasp*) -- and these really should be at least mentioned to not be auto-boxed (lame Java pun) into a certain way (C/C++ e.g.) of thinking -- especially when talking about language design theory.

Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

No. A function is not nothing more than an abstract variable.

Comment: Double-negative, no explanation...and what there is is either incorrect or incomplete, depending on the language used.

Comment: I feel I gave the question the consideration that it deserved. As for the double negative, I was simply responding in kind (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_You_Is_or_Is_You_Ain't_My_Baby).